# Jqueryeffect on dropdownmenu, the effect is not the same on all elements.

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, contact-form

I am having a problem regarding a jquery dropdownmenu. I have put a "slidedown" and a "delay" effect on it with jquery, but this only works properly if you are hovering over the links from right to left. When you hover the other way, the delay effect takes first priority before the slidedown. I am fairly new to jquery so I am having a hard time understanding this. Does this have anything to do with the html element order?

I have tried adding a "z-index" to the active link element in jquery, I have also tried to "hide" all the underlinks that are not active, but none of it has worked.

Secondly I have a jqueryproblem with the last part of the code, where I am trying to hide the text in the input forms and textarea of my contactform. I have used a code I got from http://cssglobe.com/post/2494/using-form-labels-as-text-field-values-free-script, and everything works fine except the last line when it is supposed to hide the text when you click in the field where the text is.

The jquery code is displayed underneath, and to view the dropdownmenu, visit this site: http://www.vstil.com

```
$(document).ready(function(){



 $("ul li").mouseenter(function(){

    $("ul",this).stop(true,true).slideDown("slow");


         }).bind("mouseleave",function(){
    $("ul",this).delay(500).slideUp("slow");
 });        



 $('form input[type="text"], textarea').each(function(){
    var theLabel = $(this).prev('label');


    $(this).css("color", "grey").attr('value',theLabel.html());


    theLabel.hide();
    }); 

});
```

If anyone would like to look at this I would be very greatful!

Best regards

Vegar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code. Adding z-index

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("ul li").mouseenter(function(){
    $("ul",this).stop(true,true).css("z-index", 10).slideDown("slow");
  }).bind("mouseleave",function(){
    $("ul",this).css("z-index",2).delay(500).slideUp("slow");
});
```

### EDIT:

```
$('form input[type="text"], textarea').on("focus", function() {
  $this = $(this); 
  if ( $this.val() === $this.attr("data-text") ) $this.val("");
});
```

Add an attribute to your inputs and textarea data-text="textOFLabel" and remove the labels.

Example:

```
<input type="text" value="textOFLabel" data-text="textOFLabel">
```

Comment: Thank you Taro! When I tried "z-index" I put the numbers in qoutation marks, maybe thats why it dident work. The contactform is still a bit tricky, after I added your code the text now appears two times, both inside and outside the forms/textarea. And the text outside is the one who diseappear when you click it. Also, I added a active link to "kontakt" on http://www.vstil.com, when you are in this underlist the menu is ignoring the slidedowneffect all together. Its just drops down. Any ideas to why? Again, thanks for your answer, you fixed my major problem, which was the z-index problem!

Comment: I edited the code with an example. It's an idea how to solve the input problem. Regarding the list ignoring slidedown, try removing `.stop(true,true)` in mouseenter acrtion.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I did try to remove the .stop(true, true) in mouseenter, but this made the menu behave weird when I hovered over it, left it and hovered back in while it was closing. It seems like the slidedown and slideup effects then kept fireing over and over. So I think its best to include it, even though I dont understand why it works fine on some of the pages and not on others.

Comment: I did not quite understand your example for my contact form, but I was thinking about adding something like:

$('form input[type="text"], textarea').click(function(){
$(theLabel, this).hide();

The problem so far is that I hide the input forms and textarea when I click, and not the text inside the forms and textarea.

Comment: I found out why the script didnt work with the .on function. This function was apparently added in jQuery 1.7, I was using the 1.6 version.